# How can I make this bitmap looking image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, bitmap

I'm trying to duplicate this. Thought it would be a low-resolution bitmap effect but somehow I can't achieve those patterns. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I can't think of a way to use Photoshop for this, but something similar is possible using Inkscape.  It has a Tiled Clones Trace function which can be use to create a halftone screen over the top of an image. You can make the initial shape a square: [see example](https://imgur.com/14bsdjV). If you are interested in doing this, there's [a youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/kNKPtQ4IWPQ?si=JpywMPmz1mIAAWdl) from Logos by Nick which shows how to use this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I was sure I had seen this kind of effect made with Photoshop before, so I played around a bit myself. I *did* find something that comes visually close to your imgage, but it may or may not be suitably for your particular application.

What I did step by step was:

- create a simple elipse, then rasterize it
- merge that elipse with a white background/layer
- apply **Pixelate>Mosaic** effect (I used a Cell Size of 6 for a 10pt stroke in the example below)
- apply Filter **Gallery>Brush Strokes>Accented Edges** filter with the following settings

[image: Accented Edges]

And the result was this:
[image: Sample Image]

**Mosaic Cell Size** and **Edge Width** basically define the result here.
You can also apply levels afterwards to reduce/eliminate gray "pixels" for 2-bit color.

I hope this is close to what you were looking for or can at least be helpful in any way.